# How to change the value of a custom radio button field programmatically?

Tags: custom-fields, profile, php, forms

I have a CiviCRM profile that hosts a custom field. The custom field is of type "Radio-Button" and hosts two options:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is changing the values of each option programmatically when the form gets built. According to the [hook reference](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/), the `buildForm` hook should be used for doing such changes.

I know it's possible to change default values for simple input fields, it can be done by calling the `$form->setDefaults( $defaults )` function. But how does one modify more complicated HTML form elements such as radio buttons?

I browsed the `CRM_Core_Form` [PHP class reference](https://doc.symbiotic.coop/dev/civicrm/v47/phpdoc/CRM_Core_Form.html) and cannot find the appropriate functions.

Answer (score 1):

If the options that are shown on the profile are custom fields, then the radio options displayed might be the option values of some option groups.

To add/remove any options from the profile, you can make use of [`fieldOpions`](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_fieldOptions) hook. Eg -

```
function hook_civicrm_fieldOptions($entity, $field, &$options, $params) {
  //replace 1 with your custom address field id
  if ($field == 'custom_1') { 
    $options['my_option'] = 'My Custom Option';
  }
}
```

Check the doc for more info about the param, etc.